# Ubuntu 14.04, dpkg-reconfigure select option unattended

Tags: 14.04, apt, xorg, dpkg

Via a script I am attempting to configure x11-common.  Manually I have been able to run the command:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure x11-common`

then selected `Anybody` which worked.

I would like to programmatically provide the `Anybody` answer to the command.

I have tried `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive x11-common`

How is this possible?

Comment: What does `debconf-get-selections | grep x11-common` say?

Comment: One second rebooting and reprovisioning VM.  I'm assuming it says "Console-only".  Should be able to echo an answer to `debconf/x11-common`?

Comment: Also, from `man dpkg-reconfigure`: Note that if you normally have debconf set to use the noninteractive frontend, dpkg-reconfigure will use the dialog frontend instead, so you actually get
           to reconfigure the package.

Comment: Yes it says:    `x11-common x11-common/xwrapper/allowed_users select Console Users Only
x11-common x11-common/xwrapper/actual_allowed_users string console`

Comment: I see so `debconf-set-selections`.

Comment: Even if you use `debconf-set-selections` (which you can indeed use to preseed settings before installation), `dpkg-reconfigure` will still show the prompt (because that's what it's intended to do). Normal `dpkg` operations won't show the prompt if `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` is set.

Comment: Still some confusion.  I echoed `echo x11-common x11-common/xwrapper/allowed_users select Anybody | sudo debconf-set-selections
echo x11-common x11-common/xwrapper/actual_allowed_users string anybody | sudo debconf-set-selections`  which sets debconf correctly, however Openbox throws `Failed to open the display from the DISPLAY environment varibale`.  Only setting `Anybody` manually via `sudo dpkg-reconfigure x11-common` works

Comment: Is it `anybody` or `Anybody`?

Comment: Sorry `Anybody`.  Corrected above.

Comment: Did you install `x11-common` after you set the selection or before?

Comment: Ah had it set after installation :(.  Giving it another go.  Thank you!

Comment: Seems to work great. Thank you.  Issue seemed to be caused by my upstart script which I will debug.  Please compile into answer and would be happy to select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `debconf-set-selections` to preseed settings for such configuration scenes. First, on a system on which the package has been installed and configured, run:

```
debconf-get-selections | grep x11-common
```

This will tell you the selection identifiers (the name of the package, which you know, and the name and type of the question) you need in case you want to manually set them. In this case, the output would be something like:

```
x11-common  x11-common/xwrapper/allowed_users         select  Anybody
x11-common  x11-common/xwrapper/actual_allowed_users  string  anybody
```

Then you can do, on a system on which `x11-common` is yet to be installed, you can:

```
ssh first-system 'debconf-get-selections | grep x11-common' |
  sudo debconf-set-selections
```

Or, manually:

```
sudo debconf-set-selections <<EOF
x11-common  x11-common/xwrapper/allowed_users         select  Anybody
x11-common  x11-common/xwrapper/actual_allowed_users  string  anybody
EOF
```

*Then*, you can install `x11-common` and expect it use this setting while configuration:

```
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install x11-common
```